# run php code before all requests

Tags: php, nginx

I have a chunk of php code that I'd like to execute/include on each request on my server **without** having to alter each php file in my codebase. Is there a way to do this while using NGINX and php 5.3 on CentOs 6?

Comment: I'm not sure about NGINX, but with Apache on various Linux distros, i've set up a php_auto_prepend file in the apache config of the virtual host.  That may point you in the right direction.

Comment: what makes this question off topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `auto_prepend_file` configuration directive.